# Can't read a number

Tags: java

So I'm solving a problem that requires some transformation of some number of strings but I can't even read the number of strings (integer). Here's the code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> board = new ArrayList<String>();
int num = scan.nextInt();
int num1 = 0;
String num2 = "";
String word = "";
String word1 = "";
for (int i=0; i<=num; i++) {
  word = scan.nextLine();
  if (word.length() >10) {
    num1 = word.length()-2;
    num2 = Integer.toString(num1);
    word1 = word.charAt(0) + num2 + word.charAt(word.length()-1);
    board.add(word1);
  } else {
  board.add(word);
  }
  for (i=0; i<=num; i++) {
    System.out.println(board.get(i));
  }
}
   }
    }
```

The error I meet is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: On whichever line throws the error, you're trying to read the second element in an array that has only one element.

Comment: Isolate the line that this issue is happening on in your question.

Comment: ` for (i=0; i<=board.size(); i++)`

Comment: Check the size of board ArrayList as you have no check implemented if it is empty.

Comment: the program ran fine but when i enter a number for num in the input, the error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was your intent do do something like this? Otherwise, why you have inner loop reusing the same variable i?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> board = new ArrayList<String>();
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        int num1 = 0;
        String num2 = "";
        String word = "";
        String word1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            word = scan.nextLine();
            if (word.length() > 10) {
                num1 = word.length() - 2;
                num2 = Integer.toString(num1);
                word1 = word.charAt(0) + num2 + word.charAt(word.length() - 1);
                board.add(word1);
            } else {
                board.add(word);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            System.out.println(board.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```